# How to simple bind joined tables from Entity Data Model 4 (.edmx) to Gridview thru c#?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4, ado.net

I have these two tables in MySql:

[Person]
PersonId
NameFirst
NameLast

[Email]
EmailId
PersonId
EmailAddress

In VS2010, I added a new item, ADO.NET Entity Data Model. I connect to MySql and "drag-and-drop" my the two tables into the .edmx designer. Great! It has relationships and all.

Now I want to bind something like this to a Gridview **WITHOUT using an EntityDataSource control**:
*SELECT * FROM Person INNER JOIN Email ON Person.PersonId = Email.PersonId*

How am I to do this programmatically using the modern approach? I noticed in my .edmx, the tables have "Navigation Properties" and the related tables are listed there. I just don't know the concept and syntax to use it since my skills are still "DataSet-SQL Queries-DataAdapter" based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with something like this:

```
var query = from x in Context.Persons         // Entity set on your context
            from y in x.Emails                // Navigation property
            select new PersonProjection       // Your custom class for flattened result  
                {
                    PersonId = x.PersonId, 
                    FirstName = x.NameFirst,
                    LastName = x.NameLast,
                    EmailId = y.EmailId,
                    EmailAddress= y.EmailAddress
                };

gridView.DataSource = query.ToList();
gridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks! This syntax and concept (context and projection) is new to me. I'd have to read some more.